# How does Islam deal with habitual beggary?

Tags: fiqh, sadaqah

Some people take up beggary driven by physical disability and some, especially children, are forced to do it. On the other hand there are a lot of people who take up beggary out of laziness.

Islam mandates zakaat to help poor. Zakaat eliminates beggary to an extent but what about habitual beggars who can otherwise earn a living? How should the lazy and habitual beggars be dealt with according to shariyah?

Some people abuse and drive away the habitual beggars. That is of course not what Islam teaches. Then what does the Shariah teach us to discourage habitual beggary as it is against the National Pride?

Comment: See also: Something which I [found](http://www.questionsonislam.com/article/giving-money-beggars). Besides, if you have the ability to *assure* that a particular beggar does it regularly, why don't you help him find a job which he is good at?

Comment: Please check this [site](http://www.quranandhadith.com/begging-asking-others-for-help/). I believe it is good.

Answer (score 2):

Allah says that the real poor people who deserves to be helped most are the ones who are embarrassed to beg:

> إِن تُبْدُواْ الصَّدَقَاتِ فَنِعِمَّا هِيَ وَإِن تُخْفُوهَا وَتُؤْتُوهَا الْفُقَرَاء فَهُوَ خَيْرٌ لُّكُمْ وَيُكَفِّرُ عَنكُم مِّن سَيِّئَاتِكُمْ وَاللّهُ بِمَا تَعْمَلُونَ خَبِيرٌ
>   If you disclose your charitable expenditures, they are good; but if you conceal them and give them to the poor, it is better for you, and He will remove from you some of your misdeeds [thereby]. And Allah , with what you do, is [fully] Acquainted.
>   لَّيْسَ عَلَيْكَ هُدَاهُمْ وَلَكِنَّ اللّهَ يَهْدِي مَن يَشَاء وَمَا تُنفِقُواْ مِنْ خَيْرٍ فَلأنفُسِكُمْ وَمَا تُنفِقُونَ إِلاَّ ابْتِغَاء وَجْهِ اللّهِ وَمَا تُنفِقُواْ مِنْ خَيْرٍ يُوَفَّ إِلَيْكُمْ وَأَنتُمْ لاَ تُظْلَمُونَ
>   Not upon you, [O Muhammad], is [responsibility for] their guidance, but Allah guides whom He wills. And whatever good you [believers] spend is for yourselves, and you do not spend except seeking the countenance of Allah . And whatever you spend of good - it will be fully repaid to you, and you will not be wronged.
>   لِلْفُقَرَاء الَّذِينَ أُحصِرُواْ فِي سَبِيلِ اللّهِ لاَ يَسْتَطِيعُونَ ضَرْبًا فِي الأَرْضِ يَحْسَبُهُمُ الْجَاهِلُ أَغْنِيَاء مِنَ التَّعَفُّفِ تَعْرِفُهُم بِسِيمَاهُمْ لاَ يَسْأَلُونَ النَّاسَ إِلْحَافًا وَمَا تُنفِقُواْ مِنْ خَيْرٍ فَإِنَّ اللّهَ بِهِ عَلِيمٌ
>   [Charity is] for the poor who have been restricted for the cause of Allah , unable to move about in the land. An ignorant [person] would think them self-sufficient because of their restraint, but you will know them by their [characteristic] sign. They do not ask people persistently [or at all]. And whatever you spend of good - indeed, Allah is Knowing of it.
>   الَّذِينَ يُنفِقُونَ أَمْوَالَهُم بِاللَّيْلِ وَالنَّهَارِ سِرًّا وَعَلاَنِيَةً فَلَهُمْ أَجْرُهُمْ عِندَ رَبِّهِمْ وَلاَ خَوْفٌ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلاَ هُمْ يَحْزَنُونَ
>   Those who spend their wealth [in Allah 's way] by night and by day, secretly and publicly - they will have their reward with their Lord. And no fear will there be concerning them, nor will they grieve.
>   *Bakara 271-274 (2 / 271-274)*

According to [5:35](http://quran.com/5/35), Muslims must develop methods and seek means (by the government or by civil organizations) to find the ones who are really poor, those not faking it.

Also, note that, it is forbidden to scold someone who is asking for something:

> وَأَمَّا السَّائِلَ فَلَا تَنْهَرْ
>   And as for the petitioner, do not repel [him].
>   *Duha 10 (93/10)*

Comment: In 93/10, "تَنْهَرْ" is translated as "do not repel (him)", but it has a closer meaning to "do not offend (him)".

Comment: But how to deal with habitual beggars?

Answer (score 1):

It is not good to beg but if needed beg from people who are good.

> [Narrated Ibn al-Firasi](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/9/91):
>
> Al-Firasi asked the Apostle of Allah (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam):
>   May I beg, Apostle of Allah? The Prophet (sallallahu 'alaihi wa
>   sallam) said: No, but if there is no escape from it, beg from the
>   upright.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا قُتَيْبَةُ بْنُ سَعِيدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا اللَّيْثُ بْنُ سَعْدٍ،
>   عَنْ جَعْفَرِ بْنِ رَبِيعَةَ، عَنْ بَكْرِ بْنِ سَوَادَةَ، عَنْ
>   مُسْلِمِ بْنِ مَخْشِيٍّ، عَنِ ابْنِ الْفِرَاسِيِّ، أَنَّ
>   الْفِرَاسِيَّ، قَالَ لِرَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم أَسْأَلُ يَا
>   رَسُولَ اللَّهِ فَقَالَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ لاَ وَإِنْ
>   كُنْتَ سَائِلاً لاَ بُدَّ فَاسْأَلِ الصَّالِحِينَ ‏"‏ ‏.‏

The Prophet said that the poor person is not the one who asks or begs, but the poor person is the one who does not ask and show his poverty.

> [Narrated Abu Huraira](http://sunnah.com/urn/42180):
>
> The Prophet said, "The poor person is not the one for whom a date or
>   two or a morsel or two (of food is sufficient but the poor person is
>   he who does not (beg or) ask the people (for something) or show his
>   poverty at all. Recite if you wish, (Allah's Statement): "They do not
>   beg of people at all." (2.273)
>
> حَدَّثَنَا ابْنُ أَبِي مَرْيَمَ، حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ جَعْفَرٍ،
>   قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي شَرِيكُ بْنُ أَبِي نَمِرٍ، أَنَّ عَطَاءَ بْنَ
>   يَسَارٍ، وَعَبْدَ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنَ أَبِي عَمْرَةَ الأَنْصَارِيَّ،
>   قَالاَ سَمِعْنَا أَبَا هُرَيْرَةَ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ يَقُولُ قَالَ
>   النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ لَيْسَ الْمِسْكِينُ الَّذِي
>   تَرُدُّهُ التَّمْرَةُ وَالتَّمْرَتَانِ وَلاَ اللُّقْمَةُ وَلاَ
>   اللُّقْمَتَانِ‏.‏ إِنَّمَا الْمِسْكِينُ الَّذِي يَتَعَفَّفُ
>   وَاقْرَءُوا إِنْ شِئْتُمْ يَعْنِي قَوْلَهُ ‏{‏لاَ يَسْأَلُونَ النَّاسَ
>   إِلْحَافًا‏}‏‏"‏

Answer (score 0):

It is encouraged.

> (..) [Righteousness is the one who] gives wealth, in spite of love for it, to the kinsfolk, to the orphans, and to the Al-Masakin (the needy) and to the wayfarer, **and to those who ask**, (...)
>   [*Quran 2:177*]